# Correct architecture for a cdn-fronted image resizing api?

Tags: cdn

I'm building out the api's for a new service, one of which allows image uploads. New uploads will automatically be resized and several versions created and stored remotely (s3 or azure storage). That much is already working fine.

Now I'm running into a conceptual gap about how to tie in a cdn such as Cloudflare as well as keeping a custom sub domain that works seemlessly for the cdn, cloud storage, and dynamically generated from the api.

I know Cloudflare will pull from the backing api if it doesn't have a file cached. If the api checks if the file is stored and issues a 302, will the cdn automatically then pull the file from the s3/azure? Or is there a different way to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

No, cloudflare will deliver the 302 to the client. The backing api needs to pull from s3 or azure and return cacheable bytes to cloudflare. The common implementation is to not think of this as an api, rather it is just a proxy, and it gets deployed on ec2 (for the s3 use case).